# Devise: how to migrate users from one project to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, postgresql, devise

Wondering if anyone tried this before, I'm trying to migrate devise users from one project(postgres) to another(mongoid).
I've created a script with takes users from sql table and create mongo inserts out of it, all was running fine, but for some reason devise on new project not able to auth migrated users.

*encrytpted_password* field looks ok.
Can someone please advise if I've missed something?

Comment: Did you insert the raw encrypted_password into project 2?

Comment: yes, like hash string `"$2a$10$I7cRIq....."`

Comment: Maybe the Bcrypt salt or cost in the Mongoid project does not match?

Comment: @max I just not sure where to find salt ( don't know about cost).   As I understand devise by default doesn't store salt as separate attribute (column) in table.